# how do i make countdown updated everyday from timepiker

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime date2 = dateTimePicker1.Value;

        TimeSpan Ts = date2 - date1;
        double days = Ts.TotalDays;
        txtDateDiff.Text = (days).ToString("0");
```

this is my code and it,s work fine give me a day diff but I need it to update every day as a countdown till zero

Comment: use Timer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-6.0

Comment: thanks alot i will tray this code and i hope it,s work